# Как сделать двойной фон при наведении?

Tags: html, css

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Ребята,как сделать такой же эффект при наведении? чтобы под оригинальным изображением был зеленый прямоугольник со смещением, и на нем же(оригинале) было второе изображение и надпись.

Comment: Что за второе изображение?

Comment: С помощью теней

Answer (score 2):

Используйте псевдокласс `:after`
Т.е. у вас должен быть написан следующий стиль:

```
.image-block:hover:after{
    position: absolute;
    z-index: -1;
    content: '';
    width: 100%;
    height:100%;
    top: 10px;
    left: 10px;
    background: 'green';    
}
```

Для этого псевдокласса обязательно указывается content, иначе он не будет отображаться. У `image_block` - позиционирование `relative` - это нужно для того чтобы `position: absolute` для псевдокласса работал относительно этого блока. z-index прописываете отрицательный, чтобы было под картинкой, а картинку - фоном.

Для того чтобы получить рамку - делаете уже псевдокласс `:before` у которого характеристики как и у `:after` за парой исключений - `z-index` положительный, чтобы рамка была сверху, `box-sizing:border-box` для того, чтобы блок не был больше из-за рамки. Ну и фон ставите прозрачный. И прописываете сам бордер, для бордера.

```css
.image_block{
    position:relative;
    width: 300px;
    height: 180px;
    background: url(https://www.askideas.com/media/18/Angry-Face-Animal-Funny-3D-Picture.jpg);
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: center;    
}
.image_block:hover:before{
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 1;
    content: '';
    width: 100%;
    height:100%;
    top: 10px;
    left: 10px;
    background: rgba(0,0,0,0);
    box-sizing:border-box;
    border: 2px solid green;
}
.image_block:hover:after{
    position: absolute;
    z-index: -1;
    content: '';
    width: 100%;
    height:100%;
    top: 10px;
    left: 10px;
    background: #82de82;    
}
```

```html
<div class="image_block">

</div>
```

Comment: А как же border?

Comment: @Александр добавил и про бордер с примером. Просто пример был в процессе написания)

Comment: почему width 100 процентов и хейт такой же?

Comment: <div class="a1-block" style="
  background: url(img/Layer41.png); 
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center;" >
   
  </div>

   <div class="a1-block" style="
  background: url(img/Layer41.png); 
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center;" >
   
  </div>

  <div class="a1-block" style="
  background: url(img/Layer39.png); 
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center;" >
   
  </div>

Comment: блин там когда делаю все прыгать начинает

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/Lotqpbqm/1/ а как к этому то же самое присобачить?

Comment: @FaceBook Сейчас у вас там ничего и не отображается. Но просто берете и сводите ваше к моему примеру, либо берете мой пример и подгоняете под себя. Работать с самой картинкой - в классе `.image_block`, работать с подложкой - в `.image_block:hover:before` работа с рамкой - в `.image_block:hover:after`. Нужен фон не цветом а картинкой - ставите `background:url(...)` Нужно полупрозрачным - добавляете `opacity`. Дальше уже основы. Если не знаете основ CSS - то тут уже читайте тематическую литературу, т.к. ответ по-максимуму подробный и полностью отвечает на ваш вопрос

Answer (score 0):

Можно использовать контейнер с фоновым цветом и изображение имеющее абсолютное позиционирование.

```css
.image {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  background-color: green;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
}

.image:hover,
.image:hover {
  top: -10px;
  left: -10px;
  opacity: 1;
}

.image_text {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  opacity: 0;
  line-height: 200px;
  text-align: center;
}

.wrapper {
  position: relative;
  margin: 20px;
  background-color: red;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
}

.wrapper:hover .image,
.wrapper:hover .image_text {
  top: -10px;
  left: -10px;
  opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <img class="image" src="https://res.cloudinary.com/demo/image/upload/w_200,h_200,c_crop,g_auto/fat_cat.jpg" />
  <div class="image_text">Котик не унывай</div>
</div>
```

Comment: спасибо пацаны!спасли!

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/Lotqpbqm/1/ блин,не получилось.не знаю как сделать.все прыгает

Comment: Сделай для каждого элемента обертку из div с position:relative, тогда должно быть лучше. А так сложно сказать, потому что ваш пример кода на jsfiddle отличается от того, который я привел в ответе